# To sign in, use a web browser to open the page Microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter Device Code

Tags: azure, authentication

<sub>**Note:** Answering my own question to help others in the future.</sub>

On a Linux machine in a PuTTY session I have installed the Azure CLI.

When I attempt to login:

```
az login
```

I keep getting prompted to:

> To sign in, use a web browser to open the page Microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter...

I copy / paste the Device Code so I know its correct but it doesn't work, what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you copy the Device Code, it creates a **^C** line in the console and that seems to kill the Az Login call.

The trick is to type the Device Code manually into the website https://Microsoft.com/devicelogin, see here:

[image]